# Why I am I getting color artifacts while watching YouTube in Flash at times?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-artifacts

I'm watching things on YouTube as well as hulu and at times I get this:

[image: get this...]

What could be the cause of it?

Comment: It would help if you added more information such as OS.

Comment: In addition, what version of Flash do you have installed?

Comment: It’s probably just the stream getting corrupted. As tushark said, rewinding a bit should re-download that bit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well. I usually find that clicking on an area in the timeline slightly before where I was clears this. I am not sure of the cause, but it usually has to do with too many processes running as well. I am using Windows 7 + Google Chrome Beta.